# jQuery slideToggle strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, slidetoggle

i really need help, i can't see something that is obvious, and usually then it is the best to ask for help.
I have 4 divs in a 12 column grid.Each div is clickable, and when clicked should display the corresponding div beneath it, that is initially set to display:none.

Everything is fine as long as i click on them in order from first to last, but if i first click, let's say on third div, it shows its corresponding div, but not beneath it, it shows it in place of the first corresponding div.

I am using simple slideToggle here, and really can't understand what is wrong.If i put the corresponding divs(the hidden ones) to visible, they are all displayed correctly, so it is not a CSS error.

I can provide the code, but i put it online, just click on methods tab, and you will see what i mean.

[Here is the link](http://www.vivianzoric.com/esiq/index.html)

Sorry if i didn't explain it better, english is not my native language.Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep space for these div's. Use `visibility:hidden` and `animation` but do not use `display:none` which doesn't keep space for hidden element. All built-in effect functions like `hide()`, `slideToggle()` etc. will set `display:none` to your element.

Comment: Thanks, i was also keeping animate as my last resort, but i still can't understand how one div's content can appear in a totally different position.

Comment: You didn't specify any positions of these elements. They are just floating... and if you remove one other fill float to it's place. That's what is going on :)