# Jquery QuestionAnswer with slideToggle

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

I have a simple Question and answer page. When a user clicks a question, the answer is shown with slideToggle().

This is pretty trivial but I'm stuck on Chrome, Safari and Opera but works on Firefox which is expecatable for the first three beacuse they are run by Webkit and Firefox by Gecko. I use all the latest version of formentioned browsers.

The code is this...

```
( function() {
    $('.answer-list').addClass('answer-list-display');
    $('.question button').click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    });
} () )
```

It's quite trivial and it is supposed to work.

I found [a similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232298/jquery-slidetoggle-strange-behaviour) (actually, the same as mine) but if i use `visibility:hidden`, the height of the answers remain which creates a gap between questions. I also tried doing it with controlling `height` and the animation() function  but still with no success.

All the Webkit browsers show the answer first time. But all the other times, I have to click the question three (!) times to see the answer.

I know this is a trivial question but I actually spent 4 hours of my life trying to do this, had almost no sleep and it's really frustrating.

I also found an example from a book I read ages ago, Jquery The Missing Manual who uses the `toggle()` method with two functions as arguments. Still didn't work with the same problems in Webkit browsers.

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here is the answer.

It was a markup mistake from my side. I used unordered list. All the questions were in an `li` and the `button` was inside `li`. The answers were in an inner unordered list. When a user clicks the button, the inner list would show. That didn't work.

I then switched to `div` and `p` for answers and `button` for questions and all works well.

Tip of the day: Don't use lists of any kind with slideToggle, fadeToggle(), toggle() or other animation with Jquery. It seems that it is too complicated for Jquery to calculate them and I've tried it all. Well, mostly. Who knows...